# How do we revert git repository previous branch locally and remotely?

Tags: git, ansible, aws-codecommit

how do i revert git latest branch to previous branch?

when i create my origin/qa branch,i merged it to the origin/preview branch and   pushed in to the origin without an issue but when i push into the origin from origin/preview branch. now i want to the revert back to the previous  status due to the application problem.

```sh
commit 7fc44fc5c2aa3726f131d76c1428e51450e37f26
Author: Sudesh <blah blah>
Date:   Mon Oct 14 13:17:08 2019 +0530

    check updates

commit af3e1ccf094983c00e73b7cc52c2ddf26148ee5f
Author: Sudesh <blah blah>
Date:   Mon Oct 14 11:01:00 2019 +0530

    add git repo path

commit b6053e44c4198dab8c4aee75d96d55e95e859e54
Author: Sudesh <blah blah>
Date:   Mon Oct 14 10:34:25 2019 +0530

    update the adminV2 git repo,checkout path

commit 88e537c80aed7f9300c972b2ed12097ec9d05067
Author: Sudesh <blah blah>
Date:   Tue Oct 8 15:20:14 2019 +0530
```